# PowerApps Custom Connector Azure Active Directory multiple tenant ID

Tags: powerapps, power-apps-custom-connector

I'm trying to create an app in PowerApps that will use BC Admin Center API , so when you specify which Tenant ID you want to access, I will get the data that I need based on the operations that I'm going to use.

To achieve this, I used a custom connector  oAuth2 + Azure Active Directory, I specified which tenant ID to use, and the operations worked perfectly.

Now the problem is that I don't want the custom connector to have a specific Tenant ID, I want to use different Tenant IDs that will be specified by the user.

Is there a way to achieve this multiple tenant ID custom connector? Or is there another way to achieve this (using http calls inside the app)?

My best guess is if there is a way to specify which tenant Id to authenticate to while creating a new connection that will help a lot.

I want to avoid creating multiple custom connector for each tenant ID.

I tried to use "common" in the tenant id but it only gets my Azure directory Tenant ID, but what I need is to specify which tenant to use with only one custom connector.